# Visual Studio for Mac is not synching the changes made in Xcode 11.6 and Interface Builder

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I am developing Mac OS app with Xamarin C# on Visual Studio for Mac, as my requirement is to make an already developed windows app compatible for mac or a new app for mac os similar to windows one, choosing Xamarin seems fair option as I thought of reusing some code from windows app, so I started fresh project for Mac using this guideline:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac

now when I am facing issue in synching of design code between Xcode and Visual studio, whatever UI changes, IBOutlet, Actions I am creating on Xcode, is not getting synch in visual studio designer file.

e.g. I have created IBOutlet for a label in viewcontroller.h (on Xcode), which should convert in C# code in viewcontroller.designer.cs file (Visual Studio) automatically, but sadly it is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this using VS for Mac and XCode 12.2, and I found that I was doing a couple of things incorrectly.

- It seems that XCode opens the `.m` files by default (this may not have always been the case in years past), so when I turned on the Assistant (I am working in a storyboard) the `.m` file was opened by default, but the outlets need to go into the `.h` file. I had to ensure I had the `.h` file open in the Assistant.
- When control-dragging into the .h file to create an outlet, I was placing the outlet *inside* of the curly braces for the `@interface`. This will create what looks like an outlet, but it's not recognized as such by Visual Studio. I had to ensure that I had the line pointing *outside* of the `@interface`'s  curly braces in the .h file, so that the outlet created looked something like this:

```objectivec
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageViewOutlet;
```

Once I did this, the outlet property was synched over to Visual Studio and was created in the corresponding `.designer` file.